# Display VF Page within iFrame in an Experience site for public use

Tags: visualforce, experience-builder-page, content-security-policy

I hope you are well!

I have a flow, it runs some logic, before running a Lightning Web Component. This component is there only to hold a Visualforce page inside an iframe. In this VF page, I have all the logic, script, stylesheet etc. for a stripe payment integration(payment element-to take payments). It works fine when logged in, but when using the flow in an Experience site, it cannot load the VF page due to security/access issue(I assume). It says : " [url]  refused to connect."

Console Error: "Refused to frame '[url]' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

I have included the VF page in the user site user profile, in the site settings itself. Included the domains([url]) in the trusted site settings and done all those small bits. And, relaxed all security (CSP, Clickjack etc) within the experience builder.

I would be really grateful for any guidance or help.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @VMS Hey, unfortunately not, but I recreated the VF page into a HTML page, and used that as the iframe resource. HTML was hosted on Heroku, which for my case was alright to do and step away from the VF.